# Find all real $x$ for which $\log_{10}(2^{x-1}+3^{x+1})=2x-\log_2{3^x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

**My attempt:**

$$\log_{10}(2^{x-1}+3^{x+1})=x\cdot(2-\log_2{3})$$

I am stuck after this. If the terms inside LHS were a product, this problem would have been a piece of cake. The domain of $x$ is all real here so I can't limit the range of $x$ for a hit and trial solution.

Any starting steps please?

Comment: Assuming $\log_e$ on the left, I would try $x=-2$.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is a good start.  Now evaluate $2-\log_2 3 \lt 0.416$ and note that $\log_{10}(2^{x-1}+3^{x+1}) \gt \log_{10}3^{x+1}\gt \log_{10}3^x\gt 0.477 x$ so there is no solution.

Comment: Thanks! I might be wrong but, $x$ is a _real_ number, so will the claim that $LHS>0.477x>0.416x>RHS$ work if $x<0$ ?

Comment: No, it doesn't work for $x \lt 0$.  The $2^{x-1}$ then covers you.  An Alpha plot is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(10,2%5E(x-1)%2B3%5E(x%2B1))%3D2x-log(2,3%5Ex))  Good point.

Comment: So you mean to say like this: $\log_{10}(2^{x-1}+3^{x+1}) \gt \log_{10}2^{x-1}\gt (x-1)\cdot\log_{10}2\gt 0.3010 (x-1)$. Now, since $x-1<-1$, $LHS >-0.3010$, whereas $RHS <0.416x<0$ What do I do now?

Comment: It turns out not to be that simple.  For $x \lt 0$ you need both terms on the left to not have a solution.  I am not finding a simple approach

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** power each side by 2.

$$A = 2^{x-1} + 3^{x+1} = 2^{2x-xlog_2(3)}$$
$$= (2^{2-log_2(3)})^x = \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^x$$
$$\Rightarrow 2^{x-1}3^x+3^{2x+1} = 2^{2x}$$

Suppose $X = 2^x$, $Y=3^x$:

$$\frac{1}{2}XY+ 3Y^2 = X^2$$
$$ X^2 - 3Y^2 - \frac{1}{2}XY = 0$$

Comment: I think that the $LHS$ was $\log$ with a base of $10$.

Comment: Hi OmG, so sorry, but I forgot to paste the base in LHS of logarithm. It is base 10. Thanks!